# How to debug an OSS library added to my app project by NuGet?

Tags: c#, .net, prism, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files

I have a NuGet library added to my project. I also cloned the library code from GitHub and compiled in debug.

How do I make my project use the PDBs so I can step into the library's code?

Can I do this still keeping a reference to the NuGet library? I could just remove NuGet reference and add a reference to the library project.

I tried adding a path to the PDBs in the VS Symbols settings but it didn't work (I opened a source code file of the library in my VS while debugging and put a breakpoint somewhere I know it gets hit, it didn't)

[image]

Comment: The best way to debug the library, is to remove the NuGet reference and add a reference to the OSS library. Make sure you add the same version of the library as you get from NuGet.

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to find an easier way. I got the exact commit which was used to create the library on NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky the OSS project publishes source and symbol packages to [SymbolSource](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public), that way you can simply add them to the Symbol sources, switch off "Just my code" in the debugger settings and debug away.

If you're not that lucky, but if the author has at least added the PDBs to the Nuget package itself, that way the debugger may prompt you to point to the sources, point to your local git repo and debug away. If you can find the PDBs from any other source, just copy them to your output directory and Visual Studio will pick them up and ask for the source location.

If you're lazy (like I am in most of these cases), s[etup dotPeek as a Symbol Server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/Using_product_as_a_Symbol_Server.html) or use "Step into decompiled code" in Resharper and just decompile the OSS library on the fly to debug them. You will not get the prettiest sources, but in many cases it gets the job done. Apart from dotPeek, Red-Gate Reflector Pro has a similar feature.

From the local sources you could build your own debug version of the NuGet package. If the PDBs are included and the sources are available locally, Visual Studio will pick them up automatically. You'd add a local folder as a NuGet source and it will allow you to pick your custom version temporarily.

Last resort would be to remove the NuGet package locally and completely switch to locally built sources. Last resort because in some cases this may not be possible (the code you're trying to debug is referenced by other components and needs to be strongly signed for example). And it requires some significant changes to the local project and you can't really commit intermediate results of your endeavour.

Comment: Thanks. Nope, the NuGet doesn't use SymbolSource nor does it have PDBs with it. I am trying to do this in VS and I don't have Resharper. If I build my own NuGet package and in VS I add a local NuGet source to it, how do I make VS change the NuGet source without having to re-add the NuGet to my projects? Maybe I just delete the NuGet folder so that NuGet will have to get it again and use the local source?

Comment: There's another solution I think: I could just copy the DLLs and PDBs into the \packages\Prism\ folder and I think that will work. When I am done debugging, I could just delete the folder so that NuGet downloads them

Comment: Nope, it doesn't w ork

Comment: You could use the same version number with a tag to it (making it preview) in the version and use the manage Nuget reference window to select it as you would any other (e.g. `Prism.v1.9.9.0-debug`). That way you can switch back and forth easily.

Comment: dotPeek is free and its Symbol Server option is free too. It doesn't require Resharper to perform its magic.

Comment: Overwriting the packages folder should work, but you may need to clean your `bin` and `obj` folders. Also be sure to have "Just my code" turned off  and "Souce stepping" support turned on in the VS debug settings.